# Preventing Excel auto-formatting fractions when exporting from MMQGIS

Tags: qgis, mmqgis

I export cable sizes from QGIS via MMQGIS to an excel csv. I have issues with Excel changing values such as "4/0" and "1/0" to dates when I open the exported table. Anyone know of a way to prevent this? In my research it seems that, I will need to change something on the QGIS side of things instead of the excel side of things.

I have tried common excel workarounds such as having the data be " 4/0", "0 4/0", and "'4/0" but these don't work.

Comment: I don't think you can in QGIS. You have to do it either via Excel using the [Text Import Wizard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-import-wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857) or write a small [schema.ini](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver) file to the same folder as the csv.

Comment: Thats a well known Excel issue. Unfortunately Microsoft has no intention to change this behavior. What you can do in your case is: Open the .csv file with a texteditor, open excel and format all cells as text, then copy over the data into excel.

Comment: Add some text to the beginning of the cable size cell, eg "cable size 4/0". You can automate this with the field calculator with an expression like `'cable size ' || "fieldname"`. Or the underscore character might work, eg "_4/0".